# ORACLE SQL to replace/lpadd '-' with zero(s) depending on the length of the integer after '-'

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Table column in oracle db where values vary as 4123456-1-2-3, 4123456-11-2-3, 4123456-2-221-3 etc
The requirement is to find '-' from the value and replace/padd it with zeros depending upon the length of the character/integer after '-'.
Meaning if the length of integer afer '-' is 1 then padd 5 zeros and if the length of integer after '-' is 2 then padd 4 zeros to it.

The output should be like

```
1. 4123456-000001-000002-000003
2. 4123456-000011-000002-000003
3. 4123456-000002-000221-000003
```

Please help me to figure how to frame the query , i am trying to use REGEXP_REPLACE and LPAD but unable to get through

Answer (score 1):

This uses a combination of `regex_substr()` to split the string and `lpad()` to pad it with zeroes:

```
select (regexp_substr(val, '[^-]+', 1, 1) || '-' ||
        lpad(regexp_substr(val, '[^-]+', 1, 2), 6, '0') || '-' ||
        lpad(regexp_substr(val, '[^-]+', 1, 3), 6, '0') || '-' ||
        lpad(regexp_substr(val, '[^-]+', 1, 4), 6, '0')
       )
```